# accessing bash to get git information in TeX macro

Tags: pdftex, shell-escape, git

I'm not sure if this is possible, but my goal is to include some information about the current point of my LaTex file in its git source history in the PDF output of my file.

What I want to be able to access is the information the results from the following shell command `git describe --tags`

So I'd like to write a macro which triggers when `pdftex` is run. The macro would then run `git describe --tags` and then the value of that command would be placed in the designated places within the output document (namely the page headers).

I'm really not sure if it's possible to write a LaTeX macro that can run shell commands, but I'd be grateful if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: We have the [tag:gitinfo] package.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Or the newer [`gitinfo2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gitinfo2?lang=en).

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: The [tag:gitinfo] wiki needs love.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, there are the `gitinfo` packages, which offer a broad range of features.  If you are looking for a quick-and-dirty solution instead, you can use Heiko's package `catchfile` to read the contents of a file into a macro.  The syntax `"| <cmd>"` allows to input the `stdout` of `<cmd>` as a file.

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\begin{document}
\CatchFileDef\gitdescribe{"| git describe --tags"}{}

The output of \texttt{git describe --tags} is ``\gitdescribe''.
\end{document}
```

Before running the TeX file (which I named `test.tex`), I did

```
$ git init
$ git add test.tex
$ git commit -m "Some commit"
$ git tag 0.0.1 master
```

*Important:* Run `pdflatex` with the option `--shell-escape`!

> [image]